# ADF: how to copy all files from certain sub folders with Copy Activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

Using ADF Copy Activity, I would like to copy all files for year=2023 and month=10 to another location given the following ADL structure:

```
container_name/folder_master/{subdir}/{year}/{month}
```

I was trying a wildcard file path like this:

```
@concat('mycontainer/master/*/2023/10')
```

in folder path and '/**' in filename path but ADF copies no file as it seems to fail to identify the directory wildcard.

While

```
@concat('mycontainer/master')
```

(with '/**' in the filename path) succeeds at copying all the files (which is more than I need)

EDIT 2023-10-18 : The list of folders to copy is relatively small and are known in advance

Answer (score 0):

Based on Owais Yosuf's answer I came up with the following:

- created ADF pipeline that takes `folderName` as variable
- `folderName` stores an array with the names of the folders to copy
- new pipeline executes a forEach ADF activity that takes folderName as input and uses the ADF Copy activity to copy each folder that I need

Answer (score 0):

I followed the below steps and able to achieve your requirement by using wild card path.

This is source file structure:

```
sourcedata
        folder_master
                folder1
                        2022
                        2023
                            10
                                dates.csv
                                mycsv2.csv
                folder2
                        2021
                            10
                                dates.csv
                        2023
                            10
                                mycsv21columns.csv
                                one.csv
```

Leave the file path empty in the source dataset.

[image]

In the Copy activity source, give the wild card path like below.

```
@concat('sourcedata/folder_master/*/2023/10')
```

[image]

In the target dataset, give the container name.

[image]

Now, execute the copy activity and it will copy the required files.

[image]

[image]